# I am trying to sort list of all the files in a folder on basis of modification date

Tags: python, sorting

I am a beginner and trying to write code to display files in a folder on basis of their modification date in ascending order.

I tried below code but i want to know how can i proceed to sort it.

```
import os

file_path = "c:\\albert\\david"

file1 = os.listdir(file_path)

file2 = [os.path.join(file_path, f)for f in file1]

print(file2)

i=0

for f in file2:

while (i<11):

    file3=[(file2[i], os.path.getmtime(file2[i]), s.path.getsize(file2[i]))]

     i = i+1

    print(file3)
```

I need help in how should i proceed now to sort it and print it.

Comment: You have a `for` and a `while` at the same time. I suspect that you want to iterate with the `for` loop, but you are also using an index. In this context, `f` is the same as `file2[i]`. You don't need the index. Also check the documentation on the `sorted` function, especially the `key` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Change the lines after your `print(file2)` line, for a list comprehension similar to the one you used to form the `file2`:

```
file3 = [(f, os.path.getmtime(f), s.path.getsize(f)) for f in file2]
```

Now you only need to sort it on the second element of the tuple (the modification time), in ascending order (default).

```
from operator import itemgetter
print(sorted(file3, key=itemgetter(1)))
```